# Unique validation with category for insert and update in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have list of items with related categories (table name is : `items`)

```
--- id ------ category_id ----- name
--- 1 ------- 1 ---------------- aa  --> Valid
--- 2 ------- 1 ---------------- bb  --> Valid
--- 3 ------- 2 ---------------- aa  --> Valid
--- 4 ------- 2 ---------------- bb  --> Valid
--- 5 ------- 1 ---------------- aa  --> InValid because same name exist in same category
--- 6 ------- 2 ---------------- bb  --> InValid because same name exist in same category
```

---

As In [Laravel documention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique)

Unique rule will not work here as for category wise, It validates `name` for all records.

```
public function validateItems($requestAll){
    $id = isset($requestAll['id']) ? ','.$requestAll['id'].',id':'';
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|unique:items,name'.$id,
        'category' => 'required'
    ];
    return Validator::make($requestAll, $rules);
}
```

How to validate items with related categories for insert and update in Laravel.

Comment: Have a look at this way made available in github. https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator This might help you a good example is provided as well :D

Comment: @SagarGautam : It says `Documentation for older versions`  and for like category/extra column I didn't find any clue here. Thanks

Comment: It's okay, you've already got solution congrats :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need something like

```
'name' => Rule::unique('items')->where(function ($query) use ($categoryId) {
    return $query->where('category_id', $categoryId);
}),
```

UPD: For update existing row:

```
'name' => Rule::unique('items')->ignore($existingRecordId)->where(function ($query) use ($categoryId) {
    return $query->where('category_id', $categoryId);
}),
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, How to exclude `id` here ? I mean would it work for insert and update both  ?

Comment: @user2486 please check updated answer. Hope this will work

Comment: Wow I think, now it would work now , Thanks a lot, I spent my 1/2 hrs for this.

Comment: Please also add this link for reference in your question : https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Unique.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have `category_id` in your request then this could work.

```
public function validateItems($requestAll){
   $id = isset($requestAll['id']) ? $requestAll['id'] : 'NULL'; //with PHP7 it could be $id = $requestAll['id'] ?? 'NULL';
   $categoryId = $requestAll['category_id']; //i don't know if it exists in your request.
   $rules = [
      'name' => 'required|unique:items,name,'.$id.',id,category_id,'.$categoryId,
      'category' => 'required'
   ];
   return Validator::make($requestAll, $rules);
}
```

Comment: Probably some typo. Is it throwing any error or just not working?  I'm using on my project exactly the same and it works. My example of update validation - unique:users,email,' . $id . ',id,organization_id,' . $request->organization_id,

Answer (score 0):

Create Custom Validation [Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules)

```
php artisan make:rule UniqueCategoryName
```

and change your validation rule as

```
use App\Rules\UniqueCategoryName;


'name' => ['required', new UniqueCategoryName($category_id)],
```

and in the passes method of the Rule, do the validation against the table

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use App\Item;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class UniqueCategoryName implements Rule
{

    protected $category_id;

    public function __construct($category_id) {
        $this->category_id = $category_id;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $items = Item::where([
                       ['category_id', $this->category_id],
                       ['name', $value]
                 ])->get();

        if ($items->count()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```